# Configuring virtual host on apache

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have a development machine with **lamp** setup. Now to add virtual hosts this is what I do currently:

1. add a virtual host file `<virtualhost> ... </virtualhost>` in the **/etc/apache2/sites-available**
2. add the virtual host using `sudo a2ensite <host-file>`
3. sudo service apache2 restart

This works fine and I get the desired site up and running on my localhost.

Now the problem is that every time I have to make some change to the configuration file for a site, I have to **sudo** to edit the configuration file.

What I was wondering is if it is possible to specify some directory in my home folder where apache can look for configuration files for the sites instead of the default **sites-enabled**  directory.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Is it that you want the vhost configs to be loaded from a different directory or that you have to use `sudo` to edit the config files? The latter is because of file permissions for security reasons. If it's a development machine, and you're not concerned with file system security, then you can just change the permissions so you don't need to use `sudo`. If you just want easier access to the `sites-available` folder, then just create a symbolic link.

Comment: will creating a symbolic link remove the need for sudo access? (i am a linux newbie) :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a directory wherever you want and make the permissions to fit like you want.

In Apache conf (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf) you can include the config files in that directory

Include /path/to/dir/*.conf

Apache will have to be restarted when a configuration change has occured even if you choose this solution.

Also note, that the files in there will be included when apache is restarted - there is no need for a2ensite, and nor can you disable the config files with a2dissite. The way to disable a config file included this way would be to remove or change the extension to something else than .conf.

Remember to take the possible risks into account. You will need to give sudo access, but you can give sudo access to "/etc/init.d/apache2 reload" - the reload parameter will do a configtest before restarting the httpd. If the configtest fails, it will not restart Apache.

I am assuming you run Debian or Ubunbu.

Comment: thanks fbh. It did what I wanted. I just need to configure the sudo access restriction to the **service apache** thing. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This probably doesn't matter as much on a dev server, but Apache has a graceful restart method that will delay restart of each thread until it finishes its current request. If you have other stuff running on Apache and other users to consider, it may be preferable to use the graceful restart function.

Comment: reload does a config test, if it fails it does nothing, if it is OK it invokes graceful restart.

Answer (score 0):

You COULD change the directory where Apache looks for its configuration files in `httpd.conf` file or you COULD change the permissions of the file. But the question is do you really want to do that??

It is protected for a reason you know. And you being so lazy (i.e. not willing to `sudo`) is not a very good reason :P

Or do you have to pay for every character you enter on your keyboard?

Comment: hehe :P, no i am not being lazy. its just that the development machine is used by several people. Sometimes I get someone from outside to work on the machine. I don't want to give them the sudo access

Comment: If you change the directory in httpd.conf, will `a2ensite`/`a2dissite` still work?